# handling multi level json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have those two JSON objects

```
"field_contact_phone": {
    "el": [
        {
            "value": "+30 123455",
            "format": null,
            "safe_value": "+30 123455"
        }
    ]
}
```

Second

```
"field_contact_phone": {
    "el": [
        {
            "value": "12342352352",
            "format": null,
            "safe_value": "12342352352"
        },
        {
            "value": "5454364576547",
            "format": null,
            "safe_value": "5454364576547"
        }
    ]
}
```

Although I am able to successfully parse the second object with that line

```
var popup = 'Τηλέφωνο: '+data.field_contact_phone.el[0].value;
```

When I try to parse the first one I get that error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:390

Comment: This JSON by itself is not valid. Please provide complete examples and post your code.

Comment: The complete json object is nothing more than other field elements like field_contact_phone. The full line that produces the error is edited in the question.

Comment: Well, without more information we cannot help you. The code is correct as far as I can see. So `data` appears not to be what you think it is in the second case. Inspect `data` before you access this property and verify its value.

Comment: I suppose, Error may be in main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is validated correct and working at my side. Just you need to wrap the content with curly braces( pls. see below )

```
var v1={
    "field_contact_phone": {
        "el": [
            {
                "value": "+30123455",
                "format": null,
                "safe_value": "+30123455"
            }
        ]
    }
};

var v2={
    "field_contact_phone": {
        "el": [
            {
                "value": "12342352352",
                "format": null,
                "safe_value": "12342352352"
            },
            {
                "value": "5454364576547",
                "format": null,
                "safe_value": "5454364576547"
            }
        ]
    }
};
console.log(v1.field_contact_phone.el[0].value); // +30123455
console.log(v2.field_contact_phone.el[0].value); //12342352352
```

Comment: The full json is wrapped in braces I just did not included it because of sensitive data. In fact it comes from Drupal Services node output.

Comment: can you traced the error in main.js ? You should have given that code rather than json data.

Comment: Line 390 is the the one that I posted, creating the popup variable.

Comment: Try data.field_contact_phone.el[0]["value"]. It should work. and vote if it is helpful.

Comment: `data.field_contact_phone.el[0]["value"]` is the same as `data.field_contact_phone.el[0].value`, there will be no difference. No statement can be made about the error because there is not enough information. The problem is with `data` somehow.

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks! I need some background info about the difference though because now an error with another field popups.

Comment: @TsipizidisCharalampos, Felix is correct. So, how did you get data in second json ? Did you tried consoling in firebug ?

Comment: Its a phonegap application. I am using adb and weinre for debugging. The data is ok in the second json because alert(popup); produces the correct string. On the contrary with the first json it produces an error

Comment: The problem was indeed with the data. Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: gr8 ! I am glad to know that !!